# How to find out from which scene the segue happend?

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have multiple view controllers that take you to a common view controller using prepareforsegue method. The problem is how do i find out in the common view controller that from which controller it got segue to....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A segue object has `source` and `destination` properties that you can look at. So, from the common destination view controller, you can look at the `source` of the segue.